CreatinIOS APP Intent With Expo React Native
I am trying to integrate ios app Intent on expo using the expo native modules, documentation can be found here - https://docs.expo.dev/modules/native-module-tutorial/
I created a module with the npx create-expo-module sample-app-module command. The folders were created.
My major question is where to add the app intent code.

@available(iOS 16, *)
struct SampleAppIntent: AppIntent {
    static let title: LocalizedStringResource = "AppName Session"
    static var openAppWhenRun: Bool = false

    
    func perform() -> some IntentResult & ProvidesDialog {
        return .result(dialog: "How can i help you today?")
    }
}

@available(iOS 16, *)
struct SiriAppShortcuts: AppShortcutsProvider {
     static var appShortcuts: [AppShortcut] {
         AppShortcut(
             intent: SampleAppIntent(),
             phrases: [
                "Start a session with \(.applicationName)",
                "Book a session with \(.applicationName)",
                "\(.applicationName) session",
             ]
         )
}
}

I currently added it to the moduleSwift file, but it doesnt work, can someone please assit.
How i know it doesnt work is that i cant find the shortcut after i install the app development client on my tab or simulator

did you ever figure this out?
